# Change iframe width and height using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

I have tried a solution that I found on this website. However, it did not work for me. I am thinking there is a script that is setting this somewhere else so I need to add some code in the page to overide the style.

I tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#frame1").width(578);
        $("#frame1").height(326);
    });
</script>
```

However, the html still comes out like this:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/20657168?color=fc030f" style="width: 500px; height: 281.25px;"></iframe>
```

I want the `width` to be `578` and the `height` to be `326`. Here is the website: http://beckindesigns.tumblr.com/

P.S. If I add a class or ID it strips it from the html. I am using Tumblr..

Comment: where is your frame1 id?

Comment: You need to give the iframe `id="frame1"`.

Comment: Tumblr is stripping the ID from the video post...

Comment: @tech0925 updated my answer to show how to do it without ID.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It will work if you add `id="frame1"` to your `iframe`.

```
<iframe frameborder="0" id="frame1" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/20657168?color=fc030f" style="width: 500px; height: 281.25px;"></iframe>
```

The `$("#frame1")` will select the element with the id attribute `frame1`. For reference: [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and [ID Selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).

**Update:** Since you said that the ID is getting stripped out, you can just change how the selector is working, and apply it to all iFrames:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("iframe").width(678);
        $("iframe").height(526);
    });
</script>
```

If you have multiple iFrames on page and you don't want them to be the same size, you can use the [:eq(index)](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/eq) selector, which will match on the zero-based index. So if you have two iFrames on the page, and only want to change the second, use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("iframe:eq(1)").width(678);
        $("iframe:eq(1)").height(526);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I tried both and my html keeps outputting the same :( `<iframe frameborder="0" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/20657168?color=fc030f" style="width: 500px; height: 281.25px;">`

Comment: Yes - the rendered output in HTML won't match the values set by jQuery... but the size of the iframe will be correct. jQuery is changing the size of the iframe but it isn't going to change the actual HTML as you see it when you "view source".

Comment: Instead of "view source" you can "inspect element" in Chrome and you should see the correct values, which will still differ from the initial HTML that was served up to client.

Comment: Ok I see what you are saying now. However, b/c of the inline style="" that is in the iframe it stays the old size and it won't expand.

Comment: I found a work around. Tumblr is horrible! Instead of posting a video post if I post a text post and then just include the iframe I can use the id. Well, that will work :) LOL

Comment: The inline style will not override the values jQuery sets. Maybe the jQuery isn't running. What happens if you put an `alert('test');` in there too?

Comment: Its popping that up. But it still won't change the size of the video like the one below it. The top one is a video post which strips the ID and the one below that is a text post that allows me to keep the ID. http://beckindesigns.tumblr.com Any ideas?

Comment: I just uploaded some sort of javascript file that allow me to use css and over ride the inline CSS. Don't know how it works but love it!

Comment: IDK the only jQuery code I see on that page is still using the old ID selector: `$("#frame1").width(578);`

Answer (score 1):

Adjust iframe to window size

```
<iframe frameborder="0" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/20657168?color=fc030f" style="width: 500px; height: 281.25px;"></iframe>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("iframe").height($(window).height());
       $("iframe").width($(window).width());

       $( window ).resize(function() {
            $("iframe").height($(window).height());
            $("iframe").width($(window).width());
        });
    });
  </script>
```