# jquery - setting iframe width is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I know, this thing has been asked like 2 trillion times, but i cannot still get done. the iframes are generated dynamically inside the source which I get from external feed.

my jquery is:

```
$(function(){
   $('iframe').each(
      function(index, elem) {
         elem.setAttribute("width","250");
      }
   );
});
```

this code is not being able to set the width of iframe.

and one more thing: I inspected the iframe attributes, and there are NOT editable in browser unlike other css style - **which means, my jquery cannot also set it after DOM is ready**

[image]

what the heck? is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('iframe').each(function(){
    $(this).width(250);
});
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/each/ and http://api.jquery.com/width/#width-value

Comment: The each usage with funtion(index, element) works too ;)

Comment: @Arthur It does, but this has more jQuery-ness. ;)

Comment: @Mooseman the thing is, the feed is generating the iframe on his own, i dont know how to reproduce this for you

Comment: Try running `$('iframe').each(function(){console.log($(this));});`. This will output each of the `iframe` objects available to js. If the iframe is inside another, you can't change the width of inner iframe due to the [Same-origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Answer (score 0):

Use `.attr`, not `.setAttribute`.

Comment: Incorrect. `elem` inside that function is **not** a jQuery object. `setAttribute` is vanilla.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me with

```
    $('iframe').each(function(){
        $(this).width( w );
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8e1gz475/

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple way of assigning "**width or height**" to any element at run-time, and that's using "`.width()` and `.height()`" method of jQuery.

Refer:

http://api.jquery.com/width/

http://api.jquery.com/height/

Here is an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("iframe").width(500);
        $("iframe").height(500);
    });
</script>
```

#### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hytgrpsw/1/) : Regular iframe without updating height and width at run-time.

#### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hytgrpsw/): When you update height and width at run-time.

Here is another stackoverflow question for iframe width where you can find good explanation in the answer if you are using multiple iframes : 
 **[Change iframe width and height using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913784/change-iframe-width-and-height-using-jquery)**

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$(function(){
   $('iframe').each(
      function(index, elem) {
         elem.css({ "width":"250px !important" });
      }
   );
});
```

Comment: if you send the 250 as a string, you need to put 'px' right ? 
.css({"width":"250px !important"});