# CKEditor textarea content not displaying/not updatable (Randomly)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ckeditor

Textarea content does not display and the textarea is not editable (Happens randomly)

Only when I resize the Editor (Bottom right corner handle) the content starts to appear and the Editor is editable, this bug appears randomly and only tested in Chrome. Has anyone experienced this or any solutions would be helpful?

Example of my textarea:

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="80"><?php echo $output; ?></textarea>
```

And this is how I set it up:

```
// Set the ckeditor wysiwyg editor
function CKupdate(){
for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances )
CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
}          
$( 'textarea' ).ckeditor();
```

CKEditor Version 4.4.6

**UPDATED with Screenshots**

[Click here to view screenshots](http://elroyshillingit.co.za/images/ckeditor_display_bug.jpg)

---

**ISSUE RESOLVED**

I have found the display Bug, within the output of the iframe:

Working Editor:

```
<iframe src="" frameborder="0" class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" title="Rich Text Editor,     detailed_description" aria-describedby="cke_125" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true" style="width: 704px; height: 100%;"></iframe>
```

Editor with display Bug:

```
<iframe src="" frameborder="0" class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" title="Rich Text Editor, customers" aria-describedby="cke_71" tabindex="10" allowtransparency="false" style="width: 0px; height: 200%;"></iframe>
```

Notice the difference in **width** between the two Editors/iframes, the editor which causes the issues is the one with **width: 0px**, somehow when you resize the browser or Editor it changes the **width** back to **704px**.

Hope this will help someone in future...

Comment: Could you create a live example? jsFiddle or similar.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This happens in a user access production environment/applications and as such cannot be created in jsFiddle. Even if I could add an example the issue is so random that it cant be re-created. The best I can do is to upload a screenshot when the error occurs.

Comment: I think that it's one of the recent Chrome's rendering issues. It looks like they did a lot of "optimisations" in the engine because I remember at least two more different cases where some part of content wasn't visible.

Comment: Hi @Reinmar ...I also think its a Chrome related Bug, I finally managed to take screenshots after struggling yesterday to re-create the error, updated question with screenshots link: [link](http://elroyshillingit.co.za/images/ckeditor_display_bug.jpg)

Comment: Hi @oleq I'm unable to give a live example, I have uploaded screenshots instead: [link](http://elroyshillingit.co.za/images/ckeditor_display_bug.jpg)

Comment: @Elroy: I saw your answer. In this case it may be a CKEditor's fault (some race condition?) or at some point Chrome returns an incorrect value which CKEditor uses when setting iframe's height (happened many times before). But without a sample we'll not be able to investigate it. Anyway, I'm glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The display issue is caused by the Editor that outputs the iframe with size "width: 0px".

Next step, finding a possible **solution**:

**CSS**
Set a predefined width for all Iframes, example [CSS][1];

OR

**Jquery** (Example: [change-iframe-width-and-height-using-jquery][2])

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/7WRHM/1001/
[2]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14913861/2842657
```

***I have not tested thoroughly but this solution seems to solve the issue***:

```
.cke_contents > iframe{
  width: 100% !important;
}
```